# Error code subquery uses ungrouped column from outer query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

Can anyone help me whats wrong with my code

```
SELECT agent.agent_name AS agent_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(assigned.id_agent))AS itung,
       (SELECT COUNT(ticket.id_agent) WHERE ticket.id_status = 4) AS itung2
FROM agent
  LEFT JOIN assigned ON agent.id = assigned.id_agent
  LEFT JOIN ticket ON agent.id = ticket.id_agent
GROUP BY agent.id
```

I got error code subquery uses ungrouped column "ticket.id_status" from outer query

> LINE 3: (SELECT COUNT(ticket.id_agent)WHERE ticket.id_status = 4)AS ...

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, but I think you are looking for the FILTER.

But as `agent.agent_name` is your only un-grouped column, you have to group by *that*:

```
SELECT agent.agent_name AS agent_name,
       COUNT(assigned.id_agent) AS itung,
       COUNT(ticket.id_agent) FILTER (WHERE ticket.id_status = 4) AS itung2
FROM agent
  LEFT JOIN assigned ON agent.id = assigned.id_agent
  LEFT JOIN ticket ON agent.id = ticket.id_agent
GROUP BY agent.agent_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, you are clearly missing `ticket.id_status` in group by clause.
You can either include it in group by clause;

OR

The query can be further simplified by aggregate function to calculate the value of itung2 as below :

```
SELECT agent.agent_name AS agent_name,
    COUNT(assigned.id_agent) AS itung,
    COUNT(ticket.id_agent) AS itung2
FROM agent
LEFT JOIN assigned ON agent.id = assigned.id_agent
LEFT JOIN ticket ON agent.id = ticket.id_agent AND ticket.id_status = 4
GROUP BY agent.id, agent.agent_name;
```